# Delete not showing up on other DomainContext instance

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have two instances of the same DomainContext. When I add an entity to one, submit changes, then do a reload on the other, the new entity shows up in the collection. However, the same doesn't happen with Delete. The deleted object is still in the second DomainContext's EntitySet even after calling Load again. Whats going on?

Comment: How do you execute the LoadOperation? Do you provide a LoadBehavior for the method call?

Comment: I wasn't specifying any behaviour but even after adding LoadBehaviour.RefreshCurrent its still doing the same thing (also tried the other LoadBehaviour options without success).

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/24/refresh-the-cached-entityset-after-a-submitchanges-wcf-ria-services.aspx) and it fixed the problem. Basically what is required is to remove any entities from the domain context that the load operation does not load.